# when using fglrx unity does not display and slow moving windows

Tags: unity, ati, graphics, performance, fglrx

two issues when using the fglrx driver:

when i move to the propriety fglrx driver, unity does not load the side bar. the login screen loads (with top bar displayed), but when logging in, the unity side bar does not load. i can right click the desktop and create new folders. i can ctrl+alt+delete and manage to get to system settings (where i can change back to open source driver).

any ideas?

other issue: when using the fglrx, when i open a panel say system settings), and move the panel, it lags, it moves at like 2 fps, instead of being a smooth move such as when using the open source driver.

any ideas?

specs:
i3
4gb ram
radeon 5770 hd 512mb gpu (sapphire)
250 gb sata
gigabyte h55m mobo.

Comment: Please post the result of the following command: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

Comment: Hi Tomkat, when i do this using open source driver, all answers are yes! when i am using fglrx, i do not know how to open a terminal to run this command, do you know how I can?

Comment: Terminal can be opened by [CTRL]+[ALT]+[T] or [ALT]+[F2]

Answer (score 0):

see if ubuntu unity plugin is enabled in compiz config settings. 
Also try `unity --replace` command in terminal for 12.10 and `unity --reset` for 12.04
also you could try reseting compiz to default

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwFG9XpdYEg

Answer (score 0):

Are you on 12.10? In that case this is a known bug. Please go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661 and report that it affects you too (the option is near the top of the page).

You can remove the fglrx drivers and revert to the open source drivers (which should work) by following the instructions on http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx
or via the system settings, like you mentioned.

Comment: thanks guys i have gone to 12.04 and fglrx installed and working. could be the same bug. thanks!